# Asynctask with multiple constructor / without constructor

Tags: android, constructor, android-asynctask

I cant use multiple constructor with asynctask. I need to use FetchTask(category) and FetchTask(textview) separately. [ NOT FetchTask(category,textview) ]

Is it possible to use multiple constructors ? OR Can I use a different constructor/method for asynctask ?

```
public class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    TextView Txt;
    private Category category;

    public FetchTask (final Category cat) {    
        this.category = cat;
    }

    public FetchTask(TextView outputTxt) {
        super();
        Txt = outputTxt;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
        String Str = str[0];       
        return Str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Txt.setText(result);        
    }
}
```

**FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2**

**java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()**

Comment: What do you mean, you "can't"? Have you tried and gotten errors and if so what were they? I have never tried using more than one but I don't know why you couldn't. Also, is this an inner class or separate file?

Comment: Why can't you use multiple constructors? Are you getting an error of some sort?  If so, what error are you getting and where are you getting it from?  Also, there is no need to call `super();` in your constructor unless you explicitly need your default constructor to be called.  In your case, it's not needed.

Comment: It gives FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 error.  I'm able to use FetchTask(category,textview) But cant use them separately

Comment: Is there anyway to use result without constructor ?

Comment: If your `FetchTask` is a sub class of your activity. Then make the `outPutTxt` `textView` as class member of your main class (Activity class) and you can directly use that in your subclass.

Comment: Is there any change for this(AsyncTask<String, Void, String>) in your original code.

Comment: AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String> in original code. Its working without problem I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple constructors. 
See your code :

```
public FetchTask (final Category cat) {    
    this.category = cat;
}
```

If you use above constructor to start `AsyncTask` then there is an error.
See

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Txt.setText(result);        
}
```

You are not initializing `Txt` with your 1st costructor.
And I think that you no need to call `super();` from your constructor.

Comment: Thanks for reply; I want to use  **FetchTask(TextView outputTxt)**  to start AsyncTask.  And my main class that contains FetchTask as subclass is : FetchTask   ft = new FetchTask(mytextview);    
               ft.execute(position); 
Is there any error with codes ?  Or anything that I must add to these codes ?

Comment: ` ft.execute(position);` what is position in this.

Comment: its a pageradapter ; I use viewpager with asnctask. and doInBackground contains position in it  ;  position =  str

Comment: Yes, but some more codes are in main codes that I shortened. Actually I realized that I may need to **start FetchTask (final Category cat)** before **doInBackground starts**  if it is possible ?

Comment: because FetchTask (final Category cat) has a method that sets a value, and doInBackground uses it. So it must be set before doInBackground starts

Comment: FetchTask() is constructor here. So it will call when you create an object of FechTask class. You can have any number of constructor in a java class but the attribute type or number should be different.  doinbackground function will call after you create a object of FetchTask class

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple constructors.
This code compile fun, there are other issues with it but this is not relevant to the subject.

Hope this helps, 
Yaron